# ionic native fcm plugin issue

Tags: android, ionic3, ionic-native, cordova-plugin-fcm

I want to implement firebase push notification in my ionic 3 application. I've added ionic natice fcm plugin. But when i build application using following command

```
ionic cordova build android
```

but it gives me an error as below:

```
ionic cordova build android
Running app-scripts build: --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[12:22:34]  build dev started ...
[12:22:34]  clean started ...
[12:22:34]  clean finished in 31 ms
[12:22:34]  copy started ...
[12:22:34]  transpile started ...
[12:22:52]  transpile finished in 17.82 s
[12:22:52]  preprocess started ...
[12:22:52]  deeplinks started ...
[12:22:52]  deeplinks finished in 250 ms
[12:22:52]  preprocess finished in 297 ms
[12:22:52]  webpack started ...
[12:22:55]  copy finished in 20.24 s
[12:23:15]  webpack finished in 22.49 s
[12:23:15]  sass started ...
[12:23:19]  sass finished in 4.08 s
[12:23:19]  postprocess started ...
[12:23:19]  postprocess finished in 32 ms
[12:23:19]  lint started ...
[12:23:19]  build dev finished in 44.83 s
> cordova build android
✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

        (truncated) ... aLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
        :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
        :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds900Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite900Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase900Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1102Library UP-TO-DATE
        :prepareDebugDependencies
        :compileDebugAidl
        :compileDebugRenderscript
        :generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
        :generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
        :processDebugGoogleServices
        Parsing json file: D:\Projects\Code\Other\DailySheet\DailySheetMobileApp\platforms\android\google-services.json
        :generateDebugResources
        :mergeDebugResources
        :processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
        :processDebugResources
        :generateDebugSources
        :incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
        :compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
        :compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
        :compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
        :mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
        :compileDebugShaders
        :generateDebugAssets
        :mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 1 mins 48.75 secs

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
        > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
        Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzee;

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
        > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
        Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzee;

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

It was all working fine before i added FCM plugin. My project information is as below:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0

System:

    Node       : v7.8.0
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 4.2.0
```

Also i tried to remove all plugins and platform and readded it. But no solution! :(

Comment: Any Solution, guys?

Comment: Hey guys, i've found solution. Please visit [this]](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-native-fcm-plugin-issue/96601/6) link.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-native-fcm-plugin-issue/96601/6

> Finally, i found solution, here what i’ve done: Replace
>   android.gms:play-services-ads with firebase:firebase-ads in below
>   files:
>
> build.gradle project.properties plugin.xml Also check that if any
>   version is provided after android.gms:play-services-ads:X.X.X, then
>   replace it with android.gms:play-services-ads:+

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the Ionic native FCM plugin to your app, you need to configure your app on google firebase console and add to GoogleService-info.plist & google-services.json in your app's root folder.

Try removing the plugin, adding the files and then re-adding the plugin again.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I've fixed it myself. See above comment.
Also, I'm getting another problem, i'm not getting Notifications in iOS devices.

Comment: Did you add APN certificate in your project on Firebase console

Comment: Yes, even i'm getting some json data in Xcode console. but it fails to display notification.

Comment: I hope you are trying on a real device and not the simulator. Notifications don't work on iOS Simulator.

Comment: Actually, notification is not displaying in real device, that's while i was trying in emulator.

Comment: Can you share your code that you wrote in your app.component.ts file?